# How can I send a broadcast message in Delphi

Tags: delphi, broadcast

I want to send a broadcast UDP message in my LAN, the application is client/server.

I desire to update the user interface, this way any computer send a message to update the others.
Can I use UDPServer indy, how to use ?
Thanks

Comment: Note that UDP is unreliable - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Comparison_of_UDP_and_TCP - "When a message is sent, it cannot be known if it will reach its destination; it could get lost along the way. There is no concept of acknowledgment, retransmission or timeout."

Comment: Instead of UDP I would use a TCP client socket connection which listens for server messages in a thread. A heartbeat protocol can be used to detect client or server side disconnect.

Answer (score 6):

Create two applications, one represents the sender and the other the receiver.

## Sender

Drop a `TIdUDPClient` and a `TButton` component on your form. On the `OnClick` handler of the button write:

```
procedure TfrmUDPClient.BroadcastClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UDPClient.Broadcast('Test', 8090);
end;
```

## Receiver

Drop a `TIdUDPServer` on your form, define the same port (8090) for it and add this to the `OnUDPRead` handler:

```
procedure TfrmUDPServer.UDPServerUDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  DataStringStream: TStringStream;
  Msg: String;
begin
  DataStringStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    DataStringStream.CopyFrom(AData, AData.Size);
    Msg := DataStringStream.DataString;
  finally
    DataStringStream.Free;
  end;
  ShowMessage(Msg);
end;
```

Or, in later versions of Indy:

```
procedure TfrmUDPServer.UDPServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  Msg: String;
begin
  try
    {if you actually sent a string encoded in utf-8}
    Msg := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(AData);
  except
  end;

  ShowMessage(Msg);
end;
```

To test, run both applications and click on the button. To test with two or more "listeners" you have to use another machine. That is, you can't run multiple listeners on the same IP.

Comment: You can actually can have more than one UPD Listeners on the same ip, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604826/multicast-messages-to-multiple-clients-on-the-same-machine

Comment: Switch `Active` and `BroadcastEnabled` to `true` on the Components in Delphi7!

Comment: Additionally, you should set `Active` to `true` only after setting your bindings! https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795379/2850543

Answer (score 3):

Create a `TIdUDPServer` or `TIdUDPClient` component. Both have `Broadcast` methods that should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Ok, do you have any example about this methods ?

Comment: No, I don't. I've never used them. What trouble are you having? You give it the string message you want to broadcast, and it broadcasts it.