# Indy TUDPServer Broadcast

Tags: delphi, virtualbox, indy, broadcast

I have three network adapter, two effective and one 'VirtualBox Host-Only Network'.

When trying to send broadcast with the code bellow (binding the right IP), the broadcast data getting sent on the VirtualBox Network adapter (checked with wireshark) and of course getting no answer.

```
FIdUDPServer.Binding.IP := Settings.netInterfaces[settings.sett_net_interface].AddrIP; 
FIdUDPServer.BroadcastEnabled := True;
FIdUDPServer.Broadcast(udpDiscovery, BCport);
```

Im trying to bind the IP of my real adapter to IdUDPServer (Binding.IP) yet the broadcast being sent from the wrong adapter.

When i disable the virtualbox adapter, again im getting answers. 
What is wrong here? IDE is Delphi 2010.

Comment: Are you able to loop through each element of `Settings.netInterfaces[]`?  If so, what happens when you repeat the `Broadcast(0)` for each?

Comment: @HughJones I made some modification that for im using the broadcast address of the interface. For example, for 'interface' 192.168.100.100 im using 192.168.100.255 as a destination for broadcast address. This way, i can send out the broadcast on the right interface, yet running the software on some other PCs than mine, i dont getting answers (even if i sending out on all the interface).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing the `TIdUDPServer.Binding` property binds and activates the server if it is not already, and then returns the 1st binding object that the server is bound to.  Changing the `Binding.IP` property while the `TIdUDPServer` is activated has no effect.  You must populate the `TIdUDPServer.Bindings` collection with the desired local binding(s) prior to activating the server, and then you can broadcast using the desired binding object(s) from the collection after the server is activated.  For example:

```
FIdUDPServer.Active := False;
FIdUDPServer.Bindings.Clear.
FIdUDPServer.Bindings.Add.IP := Settings.netInterfaces[settings.sett_net_interface].AddrIP; 
FIdUDPServer.BroadcastEnabled := True;
FIdUDPServer.Active := True;
FIdUDPServer.Broadcast(udpDiscovery, BCport);
// or:
// FIdUDPServer.Bindings[index].Broadcast(udpDiscovery, BCport);
```